# Get specific values from a string of php

Tags: php

Edited my que..
Value also contains some letters

I have search through so many questions but I couldn't find it.
I have  string like this:

```
Ab2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134
```

What I want to do is get all values only in output like:

```
284t810 39h1047 3700p134
```

I used `substr` and `strpos` combine to get value but it only removes portion of data ahead of first "value=" so output is like:

```
284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134
```

I just want to delete everything else and keep only numbered value which is after "value="

Sorry if there is any confusion. Using stackoverflow for first time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use this code:
with this code you get any strings that they are after `value=`.
I think this is the easiest solution.

```
$str = 'b2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134';
preg_match_all('#value=([^\s]+)#', $str, $matches);

echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);
```

@Kesh : `\s` means space. `[^\s]` means everything except space. and `+` means at least one char. and the `()` around it is for selecting the string so we can use it after the operation. `([^\s]+)` means select everything except space and put them to the `$matches`

Comment: Hey mohammad thnk u for ur ans.. It works great for my que but i edited my que just now. Came to know tht value also contains some letters like hex code..

Comment: Thnk uuu very much mohammad... It works.. First it didnt becasue there was a space bw "value=" and value lol... So i added space to ur code too and it worrrkkss... Sorry.. I m so happy thnk u very much.. By the way wht does #value=[^\s]+)# means ?  Particularly tht part after =

Answer (score 8):

Do it via regular expression

```
$str = 'b2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134';

preg_match_all("/value=([^\s]+)/", $str, $matches);

echo implode(" ", $matches[1]);
```

Here you can see [**demo**](http://viper-7.com/vJnZKz)

Comment: Thnk u very much hassan for quick reply but i ll need space or something to divide 2 values too. Or better if each value comes on new line.

Comment: @Kesh I have updated my answer please try it or see the demo.

Comment: I see it but it also shows numbers which r before value=

Comment: Edited my que. Sorry value also contains some letters it is like hex

Comment: @Hassan this code is not complete. it also contains other numbers.  I Wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead to find all `value=` and take all characters after that until a space character is encountered then implode the results using a space.

```
$string = 'Ab2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134';

preg_match_all("/(?=value\=([^\s]+))/", $string, $matches);

$result = implode(" ", $matches[1]);
```

The output is

```
284t810 39h1047 3700p134
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to substr() and strpos() you can do the following as long as you can trust the format of the data.

```
$s = 'Ab2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134';
echo "Input string: $s<br>\n";

$out = '';
$offset = 0;
while ( $offset = strpos($s,'=',$offset) )
{
  $end = strpos($s,' ',$offset);
  if ( $end )
    $out .= substr($s,$offset+1,$end-$offset);
  else
    $out .= substr($s,$offset+1);

  $offset++;
}

echo "Output string: $out<br>\n";
```

This will yield the following:

```
Input string: Ab2cds value=284t810 shfn4wksn value=39h1047 hs2krj8dne value=3700p134
Output string: 284t810 39h1047 3700p134
```

I'm guessing that perhaps you wanted to use a strpos() based solution for efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = 'Ab2cds value=284810 shfn4wksn value=391047 hs2krj8dne value=3700134';
$array_data = explode(' ', $data);
foreach ($array_data as $array_dat) {
    $data_list[] = strstr($array_dat, '=');
}
foreach ($data_list as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = str_replace('=', '', $value);
}
var_dump(array_filter($array));
```

OUTPUT

```
array(3) { [1]=> string(6) "284810" [3]=> string(6) "391047" [5]=> string(7) "3700134" }
```

Comment: The output he wants is: `284t810 39h1047 3700p134`. This is removing the letters.